# Kubernetes, How to enable inter-pod DNS within a same Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I am new to Kubernetes, and I am trying to make inter-pod communication over DNS to work.

Pods in My k8s are spawned using Deployments. My problem is all the Pods report its hostname to Zookeeper, and pods use those hostnames found in Zookeeper to ping the other peers. It always fail because the peer's hostnames are unresolvable between pods.

The only solution now is to manually add each pod's hostname to peer's /etc/hosts file. But this method would not endure to work for large clusters.

If there is a DNS solution for inter-pod communication, that keeps a record of any newly generated pods, and delete dead pods, will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a service definition pointing to your pods

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

With that you have a balanced proxy to control the inter-pod communications and the internal DNS on Kubernetes takes care of that service instead of each pod no matter the state of the pod.

If that simples solution didn't fit your needs you can substitute kubedns as the default internal DNS by using coreDNS.

https://coredns.io/

Comment: Thanks Wolmi. I do use service as well, but problem is I cannot use that service's end point address to register with Zookeeper. Each pod needs to register its own hostname. In another word, Zookeeper node needs to be able to resolve each pod's hostname.

Comment: In that case, maybe you prefer to replace the default kubedns service by other like coreDNS that allows you to control how the DNS is registered and add more registers if you need.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I had found was to add `hostname` and `subdomain` under `spec->template->spec->` , then the communication over hostnames between each pod is successful.

However, this solution is fairly dumb, because I cannot set the `replicas` for each Deployment to more than 1, or I will get more than 1 pod with same hostname in the cluster. If I have 10 slave nodes with same function in a cluster, I will need to create 10 Deployments.

Any better solutions?

Comment: Found solution, instead using `kind: Deployment`,  use `kind: StatefulSet`.  Then the hostname of each pod is generated automatically, and ping-able between each other.